# New posts that link a post using the old URL don't show up as "linked" on the sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

I've just noticed that on the most recent topic challenge, [Writing challenge: Rise to Power - 30 July 2019 - 17 August 2019](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2127/13002), there's a link at the bottom to my initial post from 2+ years ago about starting this whole thing. In fact, the end section of the post appears to be directly copy-pasted from one of my original posts on the matter (right down to my user ID in the link). Cool.

The problem is, this includes a link with the old URL - "writers" instead of "writing". The exact URL linked is`https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1275/13002`. This means that the post isn't showing up as "linked" in the sidebar:

[image: screenshot showing linked questions]

This seems like a bug - the questions should show up as linked even if it's using the old URL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, both old and new domains will now be recognized in on-site links. I've edited your example post to trigger re-scanning; other affected posts will be re-scanned the next time they're modified. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for solving this so fast!